# How to update webdriver selenium in python(Version 115/116 is not found)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've already try this type of solution

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

But I keep receiving this error

```
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_116.0.5845
```

How do I do the update manually(if you have a video that would be better)

My RPA's in python selenium is not working due to my last udpate Chrome(116). There is no way to downgrade Chrome(In my position i don t have permission).

I really want to use my RPA to cut my wor off

Answer (score 0):

Issue: The root cause is the issue with WDM to handle/download chromedriver.exe for latest chrome version 116

Solution:

Assuming you are using latest version of selenium - `v4.11.2`, you can try the 2 options listed below:

- You don't need `WebDriverManager` anymore as selenium has an in-built tool similar to `WDM` known as `SeleniumManager` which will do what `WDM` used to do. So you can remove/comment-out the `WDM` related code as below:

```
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver webdriver.Chrome()
```

- For any specific reason if you want to use `WebDriverManager`, then upgrade the `WDM` version to the latest one which is `5.4.1`. This should resolve the issue.